# Display data from json array using angular4

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli

I am new to angular so please help me. I have an api returning an array of objects containing name, place id.

I need to display this in different cards on my html page, the cards being a widget.

in the parent component under the `ngOnInit()` section how do I access this json data and loop through the array in order to display it on my page as different cards?

Thank you in advance.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';

@Component({
selector: 'app-home-page',
templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  showSplash = true
 //public events: any = [];
  events = [];

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.showSplash = true
     this.http.get("/events").subscribe(data => {
     console.log("EVENTS ARE: ", data);
     this.events = data;
     console.log(this.events)
     })
   }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    setTimeout(() => {
     this.showSplash = false
  }, 3000);
  }

 }
```

Comment: Please, share the code what you have!

Comment: You'd ideally have a service implementing a method that makes the AJAX call via `HttpClient` methods like `get`. These methods generally return an `Observable` that you can `subscribe` to, to get the requested data. You can then loop through the data on your Template by using `*ngFor` Please share your implementation so that you could be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: I have added the code for parent component.ts file

Comment: @SiddAjmera you don't need to use Ajax to do a one way binding and a httpClient always returns an Observable by default

Comment: @SanjanaNanjappa Can you create a stackbliz and show use the html please with the structure of cards

Comment: @PatricioVargas, didn't get the point that you're trying to make here.

Comment: Well you mention that you need to make an Ajax call via httpClient, which I think it can confuse people by making them thing they have to explicity use ajax to call a httpClient method..you know like in jquery. I think it would have been better if you just mention they need to call a httpClient method... and the second part I was referring that you put "generally"  the returns an Observable, which actually by default they return an Observable. Just some English clarification, nothing major bro

Answer (score 0):

This will get you the events you want.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  showSplash = true
  events = [];
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.http.get("/events").subscribe(data => {
      this.events = data;
      this.showSplash = false;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

You will have to implement a Child Component(`EventComponent` probably with the selector `app-event`) that will accept an event object as an `@Input` property. Then in your `HomePageComponent` Template, you can loop through the events like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events">
  <app-event [event]="event"></app-event>
</div>
```

**Alternatively**:

You can use the `async` pipe in your `HomePageComponent`'s Template to avoid manually unsubscribing from the Observable Subscription. Your `HomePageComponent` Class code will change to:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.css']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  events$;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.events$ = this.http.get("/events");
  }

}
```

And then in HomePageComponent's Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let event of events$ | async">
  <app-event [event]="event"></app-event>
</div>
```

Here's how your `EventComponent` would look like in this case:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-event',
  templateUrl: './event.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event.component.css']
})
export class EventComponent implements OnChanges{

  @Input() event;

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.events$ = this.http.get("/events");
  }

}
```

Comment: I don't get how i'll be able to display the data by passing it to the widget that i'm using in the homepageComponent.

Comment: You'll have to create an `@Input` property on the widget. And then pass the input property by using Attribute Binding syntax from your `HomePageComponent`'s template. I've updated my answer with the `EventComponent` code. For your case, you can consider `EventComponent` as your `Widget`

Comment: I am getting the following error in the homePagecomponent "Property 'events' does not exist on type 'HomePageComponent".